# Ubuntu displayport keeps disconnecting

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell

I run 2 external monitors via DisplayPort connections on my Dell XPS 13 with Ubuntu 20.04.

However, after several days I always find one display goes black.

Running `xrandr` shows:

```
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

and the only way of resurrecting it is to power the computer completely off, **disconnect** the power (this is critical), and then power back on.

Any suggestions on how to resurrect the display without such drastic measures?